# Angularfire trava navegador quando salvo

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Olá,

Estou fazendo uns testes no Angularfire, e toda vez que salvo um objeto na base, o navegador trava. A tela até é atualizada mas eu tenho que parar a execução da aba e atualizar a página para que o navegador volte a funcionar corretamente.

Alguém saberia informar o que pode estar causando o problema?

[image: Navegador travado]

Abaixo o código do controller quando salvo o objeto.

```
angular.module("AlbionTrading").controller("indexCtrl", function ($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {

//Pega objeto direto no Firebase
var ref = firebase.database().ref('AppSettings/');
// download the data into a local object
var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
// synchronize the object with a three-way data binding
// click on `index.html` above to see it used in the DOM!
syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "appName");


//Pega array de objetos no Firebase
var cities = firebase.database().ref('Cities/');
$scope.cities = $firebaseArray(cities);

var posts = firebase.database().ref('Posts/');
$scope.posts = $firebaseArray(posts);


$scope.adicionarPost = function (post) {
    console.log(post);
    $scope.posts.$add({
        Cidade: post.Cidade.Name,
        Text: post.Text
    });
    delete $scope.post;
    $scope.postForm.$setPristine();
}
```

});

Comment: Abre o console do navegador, veja se aparece algum erro lá. Deve estar dando _stackoverflow_ e não é trocadilho com o nome do site, hehehe.

Comment: Olá Douglas, testei novamente mas não apareceu nada no console, apenas o próprio objeto que estou salvando que mandei escrever no console para verificar.

Answer (score 0):

Gostaria de compartilhar a solução para o problema.

Aparentemente era algo em relação a lib angularfire que causa o travamento no navegador(ou eu estava fazendo errado ou problema interno da lib).

Usei de forma 'direta' como a documentação do próprio Firebase ensina. Segue código abaixo:

```
$scope.adicionarPost = function (post) {
    console.log(post);
    posts.push({
        Cidade: post.Cidade.Name,
        Text: post.Text
    });
    delete $scope.post;
    $scope.postForm.$setPristine();
}
```

Trecho de código da função de adicionar post.